# Problem requiring/including plugin files with plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, include

I am trying to write a WordPress plug-in. In my project I have three PHP files.

1. My plug-in file
2. Widget for the plug-in
3. Data installation

I need to install data table on plug-in activation. For that sake I wrote code to create table for my plug-in in data installation file. But I am not able to create data table using this file.

My code for include data installation file and widget file in my plug-in file is

```
define ( 'OTHER_FILES_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
require_once( OTHER_FILES_PATH . '/data_installation.php' );
require_once( OTHER_FILES_PATH . '/plugin_widget.php' );
```

My problem is when I put my data installation code in my plug-in file it's working fine but when I put it in separate file (data installation) I am unable to create tables for my plug-in.

Please let me know if I am making any mistake.

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)?« and/or »[Why is voting important](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?«, more information about the [wordpress.se] model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 5):

When using [`plugin_dir_path()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path) like you do:

```
plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
```

It does return something like:

```
/var/www//wordpress/wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/
```

So it adds a trailing slash, because as the documentation states:

> It is a wrapper for `trailingslashit( dirname( $file ) );`.

So remove the slash before the file in your calls:

```
require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'file.php';
```

Comment: i tried but not working for me.

Comment: I don't know more specifics about your set-up, but what I've explained definitely has to be changed. Check/debug the path and see if it is correct. Do you have the files in the plug-in root folder? @BushraShahid

Comment: thanks for your support but i checked every thing.. and if `/` is the problem then Why my widget file is working so well. :( still could not find the reason.

Comment: As said, I do not know the specifics of your set-up - without further [debugging information](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and the code you use, so with limited information in general, there are nearly infinite possibilities for your set-up to fail. You will understand, that trying to guess the reason, out of a near infinity of options, is out of the question. So, if you want me, or anybody else, to help you further, then provide the information needed to do so. @BushraShahid